# display same data in register page when get error from php page

Tags: php

i have registration form when submitted go to php page an check some data when get error send error message to same page.
i want when registration faild and show error. old data show in textboxes and form like before go to php page. 
how can i post same data to same page?

this is the map:

index.php (have form and text boxes to submit data)

register.php (check data posted from index.php and show sens success or error message)

when redirect to index.php after check data in regidter.php form is empty and clear old data. i want form filled with old data.

Comment: use jquery validator for instant validation.

Comment: Just echo the submitted data in the inputs?

Comment: @ashish patel i cant i want server side validation like uniqe data.

Comment: Where is the code? Also please put effort into formatting your question, proper punctuation and spacing and lastly read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @tara unique data also can be validated using jquery validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

- using the session;
- using the url.

**With the session:**
In the register.php page you save the form data in the session, and in the index.php file you check the session and autofill the field if the data is present.

In the register.php:

```
$_SESSION['fieldname'] = $_POST['fieldname'];
```

In the index.php:

```
<input type=text name=fieldname value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['fieldname']) ? $_SESSION['fieldname'] : ""; ?>" />
```

**With the url**:
In the register.php page you redirect the user to the index.php page with the data of the form in the querystring. In the index.php file you check the $_GET array and autofill the field is the data is present.

In the register.php:

```
header('location: index.php?fieldname=' . urlencode($_POST['fieldname']));
```

In the index.php:

```
<input type=text name=fieldname value="<?php echo isset($_GET['fieldname']) ? $_GET['fieldname'] : ""; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you have to store a data submitted before. Session would be help you. Store data in session, And when the validation failed, show the data using `$_SESSION['variable_name']` at the textbox or textarea in your form.

Example:

```
<input name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>">
```

Wish it help you.